# Date format in tomcat accesslog configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

My Springboot based web-application is having tomcat configuration like this :

```
tomcat:
    accesslog:
        pattern: '{
                     "date" : "%t",
                      .
                      .
```

and so on.
Now with this, my tomcat logs are having date printed in a format like this : [24/Feb/2020:14:06:41 +0000]
but I want them to be printed in this format : 2020-09-29T18:46:19.330Z

So how can I typecast this date to some other format which tomcat can manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify another date format you can use `%{XXX}t` where `XXX` is any of the format specifications of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), e.g. `%{dd.MM.yyyy}t`.

You'll find the other format tags in [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes).